# Image present in my db after the upload script is executed but not in the root directory

Tags: php

//Image present in my db after the upload script is executed but not in the root directory. The script have been working well in my previous projects but fails to work here.

//upload script

```
$file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$dir = 'picture/';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$dir);

$new_name = rand(10,1000);
$new_name .= $file;
rename($dir,'picture/'.$new_name);
$new_name = 'picture/'. $new_name;
```

//error
Warning: rename(picture/,picture/424) [function.rename]: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\Transact\signedup.php on line 87

Answer (score 0):

You must use $dir/$file in rename to point to the source file. In your code, you were renaming the directory not the file.

Also keep using $dir instead of using hardcover value 'picture/'

```
$file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$dir = 'picture/';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "$dir/$file");

$new_name = rand(10,1000);
$new_name .= $file;
rename("$dir/$file" ,$dir.$new_name);
$new_name = $dir. $new_name;
```

Comment: 10x @ Hichem, but am still experiencing the Permission denied error, even after allowing all permissions on the image storage folder

Comment: @davidarinze is your php script executing in the same directory as picture/ folder? Can you echo __DIR__ variable? has your file been created in $dir/$file folder which means the issue is only with rename()?